# Iterate over a dictionary to display certain values that are not None - in HTML page

Tags: python, html, mysql, dictionary

I have a database table called streaming_service where I need to get a record from it and put it on a html page. After getting a record from the table and storing it in a variable called stream. I now want to display the contents of the variable stream onto an HTML page. I however dont want to display the values in the variable stream that equal to None.

An example of stream would be:

```
{'movie_id': 1616014, 'service1': 'https://www.netflix.com/watch/81160697', 'service2': None, 'service3': None, 'service4': None, 'service5': None}
```

Below is my HTML code using for loops and if conditions. I have said that if the value of a key is None i should continue the loop. But I keep getting thrown with errors.

Any help would be awesome

```
<h2>Links:</h2>
{% for k, v in stream.items() %}
{% if stream[k] is None %}
{% continue %}
{% else %}
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service1 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service2 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service3 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service4 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service5 }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}         
</div>
```

I then tried this code but it just duplicated everything including the None values onto the html page.

```
<h2>Links:</h2>
{% for k, v in stream.items() %}
{% if stream[k] != None %}
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service1 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service2 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service3 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service4 }}</a></p>
<p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream.service5 }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}         
</div>
```

Comment: Which framework are you using, is it Django?

Comment: Add the database table to the question

Comment: I have edited my question and i am using flask :)

Comment: Mask as solved if my answer was helpful please @Jennifer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code needs many fixes:

1 - **It's best to handle the dict logic outside the template** so rather than using `stream` you can first create a stream2 dict with filtered values and using that one

```
stream = {"movie_id": 1616014, "service1": "https://www.netflix.com/watch/81160697", "service2": None, "service3": None, "service4": None, "service5": None}
stream_filtered = {}
for key, value in stream.items():
    if not value:
        continue
    stream_filtered[key] = value
# check with print(stream2)
```

2 - **Inside the template forloop you should not repeat the paragraph tag** what would the purpose of the forloop be then?

```
{% for k, v in stream.items() %}
  {% if stream[k] is None %}
    {% continue %}
  {% else %}
    <p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ stream[k] }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This assumes that you want all the p's to have the same class and href (that's most likely not what you want)

3 - Since you are using the dict.items() method and you have key and value, **use `value` rather than referencing** so you can rewrite the previous like this:

```
{% for key, value in stream.items() %}
  {% if value is None %}
    {% continue %}
  {% else %}
    <p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ value }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

4 - If you have done step 1 you don't need the `if` statement at all in the template but if you want to check None in the template **you don't need the `else` statement** since you are using the `continue`

```
{% for key, value in stream.items() %}
  {% if value is None %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endif %}
  <p class="service1"><a href="{{ stream.service1 }}">{{ value }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

5 - Since the keys of this dictionary are basically integers **you would be better serverd with a [List](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)** rather than a dcitionary